# What's the best way to remove pid files before starting a service?

Tags: systemd, services

I have a service that does not always remove its pid files when shutting down. So when it goes to start up again it fails. My system is a RHEL 7.2 system and what I want to do is have the system look for the file before starting it up and remove it if found. I need to do all of this with systemctl, or it needs to happen before someone runs `systemctl start <service>`. I have the command I want to use I am just not sure how to integrate that with systemctl for a seamless process. Here is the command:

```
[ -f /var/run/dir/file.pid ] && echo "Found and removing" && rm -f /var/run/dir/file.pid || echo "Not Found"
```

Is it possible to stick this inside of the service file that's located in /usr/lib/systemd/system/ ? If so, where would I place it? Here is the contents of the file it would need to go in. We will call it dns.service.

```
[Unit]
Description=DNS daemon
BindTo=dns.service
After=syslog.target network.target dns.service
ConditionPathExists=/etc/dns/dns.conf

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/dns
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dns -u dns -g dns -f   /etc/dns/dns.conf -d -P 17500
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

Does this seem like the right way to accomplish this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

Custom services should stay in `/etc/systemd/system`.

Since you are doing `forking`, what I would do is use the `PIDFile=` directive. When the service is stopped, it will delete the file. However, on startup, it will **not** write to the file. It's up to your service to write to it. The recommended place to have it write to is `/run`.

Comment: Actually this turned out to be not a problem with the pid files but rather the folder they were in. I was able to resolve this by using the ExecStartPre directive to point to a script which then removed the folder. I went ahead and one-upped your answer though for the PIDFile tip.

Comment: @sokel what about power failure?the case the service on boot doesn't start as  the orphaned pid exist :) best is to make a pre script to check if pid file PID PROCESS exist if not delete file ..... like https://serverfault.com/questions/743705/how-properly-handle-deletion-of-pid-file-in-service-script#answer-74373

Comment: @ceph3us /run, in majority of cases, is ephemeral (tmpfs). this means on power failure, regular restart, regular shutdown, /run and its contents will go away and start fresh on system start. A PID file really should not exist outside of /run.